# How to make AWS ALB send request origin to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

For API Gateway + Lambda, the event that is sent to Lambda contains Origin header which can be used to set the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header of the response.

ALB event doesn't seem to contain the `Origin` header. Is there a way to configure ALB to make it forward a request's `Origin` header?

This is an example of an ALB event that arrives at Lambda
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-alb.html

```
{
    "requestContext": {
        "elb": {
            "targetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:123456789012:targetgroup/lambda-279XGJDqGZ5rsrHC2Fjr/49e9d65c45c6791a"
        }
    },
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "path": "/lambda",
    "queryStringParameters": {
        "query": "1234ABCD"
    },
    "headers": {
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "host": "lambda-alb-123578498.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-5c536348-3d683b8b04734faae651f476",
        "x-forwarded-for": "72.12.164.125",
        "x-forwarded-port": "80",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "http",
        "x-imforwards": "20"
    },
    "body": "",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Comment: The ALB is just passing along the headers that the web browser sends it. In this instance the web browser did not send an Origin header. The Origin header would only be present if someone clicked a link on a website that linked to the URL being served.

Comment: @MarkB got it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure an ALB to forward requests that contain a specific header.

To do this

- Go to Listeners tab in the ALB
- Click rules for the listener you want to configure
- Then, choose insert rule, and add condition to forward customer header.

More details are on [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/restrict-access-to-load-balancer.html#restrict-alb-route-based-on-header).